# Is there something incorrect with this code? I don't believe I should have to create a new instance of object to modify collection

Tags: c#, debugging, session

I am experiencing some weird behavior that disappears/reappears based on whether this dictionary is a new instance of the object, or the old instance of the object. Let me provide all the code first.

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes a control from monitoring/Session/Database based on ID.
/// </summary>
public static void Remove<T>(ICormantControl<T> control)
{
    _logger.InfoFormat("Removing {0}", control.ID);
    SerializableDictionary<string, T> states = new SerializableDictionary<string,T>(GetStates<SerializableDictionary<string, T>>());
    ((IDictionary)states).Remove(control.ID);
    SetStates(states);
}

/// <summary>
/// Retrieves information on an object. If the object is cached to Session then the
/// cached object is retrieved. Else, it is retrieved from the database.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"> The type of object expected to get back.</typeparam>
/// <returns> Collection of data for the specific object type.</returns>
public static T GetStates<T>() where T : new()
{
    T states = new T();

    string stateName = GetStateNameFromType(typeof(T));

    if (!Equals(SessionRepository.Instance.GetSession(stateName), null))
    {
        states = (T)SessionRepository.Instance.GetSession(stateName);
    }
    else
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(states.GetType());
        string data = DatabaseRepository.Instance.GetWebLayoutData(stateName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            byte[] dataAsArray = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(dataAsArray);
            states = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        SessionRepository.Instance.SetSession(stateName, states);
    }

    return states;
}

public static void SetStates<T>(T states) where T : new()
{
    string stateName = GetStateNameFromType(typeof(T));
    SessionRepository.Instance.SetSession(stateName, states);
    if (shouldWriteToDatabase) DatabaseRepository.Instance.SaveToDatabase(stateName, states);
}

/// <summary>
/// Recreates the page state recursively by creating a control and looking for its known children.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pane"> Pane having children added to it.</param>
private void RegeneratePaneChildren(CormantRadPane pane)
{
    _logger.InfoFormat("Initializing paneToResize children for paneToResize {0}", pane.ID);
    foreach (var splitterState in StateManager.GetStates<SerializableDictionary<string, RadSplitterSetting>>())
    {
        RadSplitterSetting splitterSetting = splitterState.Value;

        if (!splitterSetting.ParentID.Contains(pane.ID)) continue;

        CormantRadSplitter splitter = new CormantRadSplitter(splitterSetting);
        pane.UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.AddAt(0, splitter); //Visibility will fight with splitter if you don't re-add like this.
        RegenerateSplitterChildren(splitter);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Recreates the page state recursively by creating a control and looking for its known children.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="splitter"> Splitter having children added to it. </param>
public void RegenerateSplitterChildren(RadSplitter splitter)
{
    _logger.InfoFormat("Initializing splitter children for splitter {0}", splitter.ID);
    foreach (var paneState in StateManager.GetStates<SerializableDictionary<string, RadPaneSetting>>()
        .Where(paneState => paneState.Value.ParentID.Contains(splitter.ID)))
    {
        RadPaneSetting paneSetting = paneState.Value;

        CormantRadPane pane = new CormantRadPane(paneSetting);

        StyledUpdatePanel updatePanel = pane.CreateUpdatePanel(paneSetting.UpdatePanelID);
        pane.Controls.Add(updatePanel);

        splitter.Controls.Add(pane);
        RegeneratePaneChildren(pane);

        InsertSplitBar(splitter);
    }
}
```

The key line to look at in all of this is: `SerializableDictionary<string, T> states = new SerializableDictionary<string,T>(GetStates<SerializableDictionary<string, T>>());`

If this line of code is modified such that it does not create a new instance of states (instead using the object saved in Session) my code gets 'desynched' and I experience odd behavior with my Regeneration methods. An object that is supposed to have 'ObjectA' as a parent instead has 'ObjectB' as a parent.

There's a lot of collection-modification going on... I'm removing a control from states and re-saving it...but I can't see where I do anything explicitly incorrect in this code. Yet, I still feel that I should be able to express the above line of code without creating a new instance of the object.

If anyone sees an obvious blunder I'd love to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: There's a fair bit of code there, can you narrow your problem down at all?

Comment: @DanielMay Well, I've narrowed it down to saying that if I remove the word 'new' things break and if I add the word 'new' things work. The error I am experiencing is visual -- when I drag-and-drop a control on the page the debugger says it will attach to 'ObjectA' but visually it appears on 'ObjectB.' There's something veeery de-synched.

Mostly just curious if I'm doing a de-facto 'nono' that I don't see. I know modifying collections and iterating over them can go awry unintentionally.

Comment: Not being able to describe a problem with your *own code* in clear terms is a major hint that you wrote something that you don't understand and can't maintain.  I'm getting lost in the T's too, you're not alone.  Scrap it.

Comment: Noted. I've tagged it with a todo for the next time I have the spare moment. :)